# Biopython translate output error

Tags: regex, string, bash, translate, biopython

I'm constructing a bash script that incorporates grep and small Python scripts ultimately capable of searching a genetic sequence file (fasta format) for strings of sequence of a given length between two sequence search strings and translating those sequences into peptides. My bash script uses two grep functions followed by a Biopython  script that prints the first few lines corresponding to the desired region.

```
grep -E -o "ATGAGTCTT(.*)TCAGTACG" search_script_testdata.fasta > ./output1.txt
grep -E -o "(.*)TCAGTACG" output1.txt > ./output2.txt

python print_int.py > ./output3.txt
python translate.py > ./output4.txt
```

The code works until `python translate.py`.

```python
from Bio.Seq import translate
for line in open("output3.txt"):
    translate(line)
```

The output for `translate.py` is the following if run when within Python

> Bio/Seq.py:1976: BiopythonWarning: Partial codon, len(sequence) not a multiple of three. Explicitly trim the sequence or add trailing N before translation. This may become an error in future.
>     BiopythonWarning)

```
'LVS'

'SLD'
```

The penultimate file that I hope to generate would have just the information

```
LVS

SLD
```

However, when the bash script runs, only the warning/error message and not the two amino acid sequences are output to the screen and nothing is written to `output4.txt`. The amino acid sequences aren't supposed to start with a Methionine, which is the source of the error message. I need the sequences in this format. Can anyone with experience in Biopython lend a hand and suggest how I can get only the amino acid sequences to output to a file?

Edit:
I've since changed the search_script_testdata.fasta file so that the expected output3.txt file would have only three lines of ATGAGTCTT which translates to MSL.

`output3.txt`

`ATGAGTCTT
ATGAGTCTT
ATGAGTCTT`

The resulting error is the same as before.

`translate.py` is a file with the following lines of code:

```
for line in open("output2.txt", "r"):
    print(line[:9])
```

This time I get

> 'MSL'
>
> 'MSL'
>
> 'MSL'

with the same error message. My understanding is that this code should work with files set up such that each line has one string of genomic sequence to be translated. There is a separate method in the biopython cookbook for dealing with fasta file format translation.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Show us the sample of `output3.txt`, and script detail of `print_int.py`

Answer (score 1):

If your file `translate.py` really looks like this:

```py
from Bio.Seq import translate
    for line in open("output3.txt"):
    translate(line)
```

you shouldn't expect any data to be directed to the standard output and redirected to `output4.txt` file.

Print the translated sequence to `stdout`:

```py
print translate(line)
```